# How to insert zeros in certain rows and make a calculation from and to the zeros row

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix that has fixed 118 rows and columns of more than 40000 samples but always with the same length.

I have the need to eliminate certain rows and insert zeros in them. 
The best would be to have a variable like

Badchannels = [number of rows to change with zeros]

...

after that I have to make a calculation with a function that I already have from row 1 to the signal before the zeros. After that the cycle should skip the zero and do the calculation the row straight after the zeros to the following row before the next zeros...... and so on... Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Unclear what you mean but if you have a matrix:

```
A = rand(118, 40000);
```

And you want to replace the following row indices with zeros:

```
Badchannels = [2 7 18 22];
```

You just have to write:

```
A(Badchannels, :) = 0;
```

This will put zeros in all columns at row indicated by `Badchannels` indices

**Edit (Block processing)**

For processing blocks which are in between bad channels you can do it this way:

```
function [] = foo()
%[
    A = rand(118, 40000);
    Badchannels = [2 7 21 22 23 40 45];

    rstart = 1; % Init start row
    Badchannels = unique(Badchannels); % Sort bad channels and make them unique (just in case they wouldn't be) 
    Badchannels(end+1) = size(A, 1)+1; % Add (rcount+1) for end condition in below loop  

    % Block processing
    for ri = 1:length(Badchannels),

        % Define stop row
        rstop = Badchannels(ri) - 1;

        % Select the processing block
        block = A(rstart:rstop, :);                

        % Careful for empty selections (contiguous bad channels)
        if (~isempty(block)),            
            fprintf('Processing block from row=%i to row=%i\n', rstart, rstop); % Do your processing here ...
        end

        % Update start row for next block
        rstart = Badchannels(ri) + 1;

    end
%]
end
```

With above `[2 7 21 22 23 40 45]` bad channels this gives:

```
Processing block from row=1 to row=1
Processing block from row=3 to row=6
Processing block from row=8 to row=20
Processing block from row=24 to row=39
Processing block from row=41 to row=44
Processing block from row=46 to row=118
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is perfect. However now I have to write a for loop that I have to do a calculation from row X to the channel before the row full of zeros.. how do you suggest to proceed?

Comment: @AlessandroDelVecchio , see the edits in my answer for that (hoping this is what you mean).

Comment: Thank you very much, this is perfect but i don't know how to make it work. I will just show you my code so maybe you could be so kind to help implement this function.

Comment: windowl = 2048;
clear indices
indices = 1:windowl:length(newsig);
clear xx, clear yy, clear XX, clear YY;

for i = 1:size(indices,2)-1
clear newsig2
newsig2 = newsig(:,indices(i):indices(i+1));
[xx,yy] = XX_est(newsig2,1,5);
XX(:,i) = xx;
YY(:,i) = yy;
end %%%%%%% This is my for cycle.. now I have to the calculation for the blocks your function selects.. but I couldn't make it work..